# Jekyll - CSS Link in automatically generated navigation?

Tags: jekyll

I just came across a pretty weird problem. In order to list the static pages I created in the page's top navigation, I used

```
{% for page in site.pages %}
<a href="{{ page.url | prepend: site.baseurl}}">{{ page.title }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

For some reason, the output after `jekyll serve` will create this:

```
<a href="/jekyll/">Index</a>
<a href="/jekyll/css/style.css"></a>
<a href="/jekyll/projects/">Projects</a>
```

Does anyone have an idea why the **.css** file is inserted here as a link?

I do call the *.css in my header as:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ "/css/style.css" | prepend: site.baseurl }}">
```

I use SCSS in order to create my final css:

root structure:

```
/css/style.scss (sets a few variables and imports elements from /_scss)
/_scss/_main.scss
/_scss/_mobile.scss
```

Final _site structure (regarding css):

```
/css/style.css
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's why the original `jekyll new mysite` creates a navigation (_includes/header.html) with :

```
    {% for page in site.pages %}
      {% if page.title %}
      <a class="page-link" href="{{ page.url | prepend: site.baseurl }}">{{ page.title }}</a>
      {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
```

Only page with a title are in the menu.

Everything with a front matter, that is not a post or a collection, is a page. So, your scss, feed.xml and so on are pages.

Give a title to pages you want to see in the menu an filter with `{% if page.title %}`.